# Avoid blank values in SQL queries and display 0.00 instead?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Display zero instead of blank

So far I have this code, what I expected to happen is that if conditions were not meet it will display zero (0.00) instead of blank value in the query.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spComputeScDiscount] 
  @CustId int,
  @BillMonth nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  SELECT ROUND(CAST(TR.[Bill]*0.05 as numeric(18,3)),2)
  FROM [EltrFng].[dbo].[Transactions] TR
  JOIN Customer AS CS
    ON TR.CustomerId = CN.Id
  WHERE trans.[Particulars] = 'Billing' 
    AND TR.[CustomerId] = @CustId
    AND TR.[Billmonth] = @BillMonth 
    AND CN.Discount = 1
    AND TR.Consumption <= 30     
END
```

Comment: If you.use th ecorrect data type, and use a numerical data type, it's ***impossible*** for the column to have a blank (`''`) value. Fix the design, fix the problem.

Comment: You're casting to numeric? That will never give you blank? It will throw an error if the string value isn't numeric.

Comment: If you mean when the conditions are not met, then no row will be returned (that's not the same thing as blank), in which case assign the current result to a variable then coalesce it and return 0.00 if it's null.

Comment: There seems to be some confusion as to what you're asking here, due to potentially incorrect data types. (`BillMonth` as a string is a big issue, but apparently not relevant to your immediate question.) Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76345400/edit) your question to clarify: what are the DDL statements for your `Customer` and `Transactions` tables; please provide some minimal data in DML statements that will reproduce your issue; please include your expected results so that we can see exactly what it is that you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting aside a number of possible issues (e.g. why is a "month" nvarchar? and why 50 chars long?) - but at the heart of your question (I think) is how can you get back a zero even if there is no matching data. I suggest this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spComputeScDiscount] 
  @CustId int,
  @BillMonth nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE @DiscountAmount numeric(18, 3);

  SELECT @DiscountAmount = ROUND(CAST(TR.[Bill] * 0.05 as numeric(18,3)), 2)
  FROM [EltrFng].[dbo].[Transactions] TR
  JOIN Customer AS CS
    ON TR.CustomerId = CN.Id
  WHERE TR.[Particulars] = 'Billing' 
    AND TR.[CustomerId] = @CustId
    AND TR.[Billmonth] = @BillMonth 
    AND CN.Discount = 1
    AND TR.Consumption <= 30;

  SELECT COALESCE(@DiscountAmount, 0);
END
```

**NB** format of the output to "0.0" should be done after the procedure, not within it. (Unless you actually do expect a [n]varchar returned.